# Outlook Web Addins-office 365 OWA getCallbackTokenAsync return "failed" but works fine with Outlook Client after recent UI update in OWA

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

Regarding the addin which we have developed was working perfectly fine before the new UI update for Office 365 OWA,

I have used the `getCallbackTokenAsync()` to get the token for authentication in code for accessing some 'ExtendedProperty' from the mail mail object. Till now every thing was working smooth , but after the ui update `getCallbackTokenAsync()` returns 'failed' only in OWA but by using same User in outlook Client the addin works perfectly fine as expected.

Cannot imagin whats wrong here, Server returns token in Client but not in OWA?
Always new updates has more complications to debug.

Is it really the update ? or something with security on browsers?

Cannot even guess because its working at one place and not other platform.

Update 1:
Detailed error object in browser console;

[image]

So here if access restricted in OWA then the question is how it comes that access is granted via Outlook Client.

Update 2: Manifest and code for callback

**Manifest------**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
           xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
           xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>0ee7b924-eb57-414f-aeb3-0230b6a768ce</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Local</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>de-de</DefaultLocale>

  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Retriever (V5) V1" >
  <Override Locale="en-US" Value="Version 5 (Stable)"/>
  </DisplayName>
  <Description DefaultValue=
   "Descriptiom">
   <Override Locale="en-US" Value=
   "Description (Angular V5 (BETA)."/>
</Description>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://addin_url/assets/retriever-icon-32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://addin_url/assets/retriever-hi-res-icon.png"/>

  <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://addin_url" />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://addin_url</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://addin_url</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://addin_url/#archived_mail_retrieve"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>

     <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
         <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
               <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
         </Requirements>
         <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
              <DesktopFormFactor>
                 <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
                 <FunctionFile resid="fnFile" />
                 <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

                 <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
              </DesktopFormFactor>

               <MobileFormFactor>
                  <FunctionFile resid="fnFile" />
                  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
                     <Group id="mobileGroupID">
                        <Label resid="residAppName" />
                        <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="TaskPaneBtn">
                           <Label resid="residTaskPaneButtonName" />
                           <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon16" />
                           </Icon>
                           <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                              <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                           </Action>
                        </Control>
                     </Group>
                  </ExtensionPoint>
               </MobileFormFactor>
            </Host>
         </Hosts>
         <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
               <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://addin_url/assets/retriever-icon-16.png"/>
               <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://addin_url/assets/retriever-icon-32.png"/>
               <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://addin_url/assets/retriever-icon-80.png"/>
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
               <bt:Url id="fnFile" DefaultValue="https://addin_url/#archived_mail_retrieve" />
               <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://addin_url/#archived_mail_retrieve" />
            </bt:Urls>
           <bt:ShortStrings>
              <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Addin-Group" />
              <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="Archiver-Tab" />
              <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Retriever" />
              <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Archived-Retriever" />
               <bt:String id="residTaskPaneButtonName" DefaultValue="Retriever" />
               <bt:String id="residAppName" DefaultValue="Archived-Retriever" />
               <bt:String id="residTaskpaneUrl" DefaultValue="Archived-Retriever" />
           </bt:ShortStrings>
           <bt:LongStrings>
               <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Decription for Addins" />

           </bt:LongStrings>
         </Resources>
      </VersionOverrides>
      </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

**Code getCallbackTokenAsync()**

```
setConfig(data : any){
  this.config = data[0];
  config_array = data[0]
  console.log(data[0]);
  localStorage.setItem('app_config',JSON.stringify(data[0]));
  Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true, "asyncContext" : this.__archiveComponent}, function(result){
    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
      let accessToken = result.value;
    //  result.asyncContext.getSingleValueExtendedProperty(accessToken);  Commented because this function is no more called 
      result.asyncContext.getMultiValueExtendedProperty(accessToken,data[0]);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
}); 
}
```

The function gets the token and pass it to the fuction but the conditions fails and goes to the **else condition** and the result get printed in the browser console can see the image in Update 1.
Update 3

```
setConfig(data : any){
  this.config = data[0];
  config_array = data[0]
  console.log(data[0]);
  localStorage.setItem('app_config',JSON.stringify(data[0]));
  Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true, "asyncContext" : this.__archiveComponent}, function(result){
    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
      let accessToken = result.value;
        //Calling a function to get the token out of current fuction.
      result.asyncContext.getMultiValueExtendedProperty(accessToken,data[0]);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
}); 
}
```

In the code above

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true, "asyncContext" : this.__archiveComponent}, function(result)
```

Line says that "asyncContext" is issigned to the **class object**(I have created object of the class) that is **this.__archiveComponent** in order to access the functions in the class with the token by using 
**result.asyncContext.getMultiValueExtendedProperty(accessToken,data[0]);**

So Now if I replace the Class Object for "asyncContext" with any string and print the token then Yes it works and prints the tocken with success, But not with Object

Note : This above code was working fine before the Office.js library update , After the update we got this issue with ""asyncContext".

If changed anything here then which is the correct the correct way to access the token out of the getCallbackTokenAsync() function. to pass on for authenticate Users??

Comment: What is the console error you are getting when using getCallbackTokenAsync in new OWA?

Comment: In browser console it ‘result.status’ returns ‘failed’ nothing more in detials

Comment: Are you trying the API on the Message Read mode or Message Compose mode? We are not able to reproduce this issue in Message Read mode. Can you provide us the error logs if possible?

Comment: I m in message read mode i ll provide the logs in next comment

Comment: I have updated the question with more delailed error object in the image.

Comment: Can you provide the manifest and snippet of your call to getCallbackTokenAsync() API, so that we can try to reproduce this issue at our end.

Comment: Updated with manifest and the code.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error on multiple accounts. Can you clear cache, inspect you network trace and let us know what outlook-web js url you are hitting. Also could you please share the response of GetClientAccessToken call, dummy image below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLWcb.png

Comment: Now to debug with other accounts I have purchased new fresh office 365 Account and tested with same code, I got the same error also on the new account "Restricted Access"

Comment: Now I get the actual problem starts with please have alook at Update 3

Comment: "The function gets the token and pass it to the fuction but the conditions fails and goes to the else condition and the result get printed in the browser console can see the image in Update 1. Update 3":  Could you please elaborate on this, I'm unable to understand which function you're referring to

Comment: I tried these examples usage where 'asyncContext' is object instead of string and API returns success. https://pastebin.com/YwhrBVAS. Is your usage different than this?